# Have trouble with iOS 9 Universal Links when adding character * in applinks as 'applinks:*.codestuffs.com' which is inside Associated Domains section

Tags: ios, ios9, applinks

In Apple's document, it said "You can use the asterisk character * as a wildcard to match variations of an associated domain.” It may looked like this: “applinks:*.users.mywebsite.com”. (Apple document url: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

But when we use character * , our link looks like "applinks:*.codestuffs.com". And we input it in Associated Domains section in the Capabilities tab of project setting. We failed to upload an ipa via Application Loader.

We encounter an error:
ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'applinks:*.codestuff.com' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/BAdaUS.app/BAdaUS' is not supported."

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Ros What is your problem? I checked our codes now and we are not using * as wildcard in our App Links. Our app links are specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means the `applinks` URL isn't valid.

The Apple page you linked to is the prerelease documentation for iOS 9.3. Using the `applinks:*.mywebsite.com` wildcard is a new feature in iOS 9.3 ([source](http://fortheloveoftech.com/2016/01/25/apple-releases-ios-9-3-beta-2-to-developers/)), so you can't submit IPAs using it quite yet.

Here's the same Apple doc page for the current public iOS release (9.2.1): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you for the referencing document url, it is great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post I wrote about setting up Universal Links: https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/